# How multiple user can login to their respective activity in android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a job related app in which I have two users 'company' and 'user'. While login, I am trying to compare the email id and password of respective user from firebase realtime database and after clicking on login button the respective user should redirect to its respective page.

```
'''
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 final String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
 dbUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Register").child(id);

                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,passwd)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {

                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            if(dataSnapshot.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("User"))
                                            {
                                                startActivity(new Intent(login.this,UserHome.class));
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                            else if(dataSnapshot.child("type").getValue(String.class).equals("Company"))
                                            {
                                                startActivity(new Intent(login.this,CompanyHome.class));
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    };

                                    dbUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    new SweetAlertDialog(login.this,SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE).setTitleText(task.getException().getMessage()).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
```

This is my database structure where user has different attribute and company contains different attribute.
[image]

This is my User.class file

```
package com.example.easyjob;
public class User {

    private String id;

    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String email;
    private String mob;
    private String type;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String name, String gender, String email, String mob, String type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.email = email;
        this.mob = mob;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMob() {
        return mob;
    }

    public void setMob(String mob) {
        this.mob = mob;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

In the same manner I have a class file for company which has different attribute.

Comment: Add the database screenShot to your question, not in link.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I want that user should login to it's homepage and company should to it's respective homepage after login .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to manually login yourself. Let the user login via this method shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#kotlinktx_1):

Now comes the tricky part, how to verify which company a user belongs to. This relies heavily on how users are added to companies. If an admin does this, then it is as simple as them adding a user's email to their company and you check the user's email against this after login.
If the user adds themselves to a company then simply check for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing i noticed after seeing your code.

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 final String id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

You are calling `getUid()` before the user hasn't authenticated. So it'will return `null` and then you're referencing to the child node of `Register` with `id` which is `null` at the moment.

You first need to authenticate the User and in the `onComplete()` method you should get the `Uid` to further get the information of the user from firebase database. After that perform your comparison.